# How to let people collaborate on my open source project?

Tags: open-source, collaboration

A while ago I started an open-source project, which for me meant (until now) I simply pushed my source code to a public repository (Mercurial on Google Code). Recently though, I've received requests from other people to collaborate on my project. Having never collaborated on an open-source project before, I'm not sure how to proceed:

- Do I just give them access to the repository so they can push changes? If they push something I don't like I can always roll back and if they get on my nerves I can always revoke their access to the repository.
- Do I tell them to send in patches (via the issue tracker) and then apply the ones I like and revoke the ones I don't?

Now:

- I don't want to lose ownership of my project. It's a pretty nice project and it's good resume material. I think this is what I am most afraid of. However, I want to give proper credit to my collaborators.
- I know this is the whole point of open-source: collaboration, so I don't want to be an idiot and say no to these people who want to help.
- Lately I haven't had much time to code on my project, so it could use some help.

Also, I'm a bit reluctant to let just anyone work on my project. What if they're, pardon the expression, noobs? I suppose I can just rollback they're changes and tell them to, pardon the expression, gtfo, but that wouldn't be particularly nice.

How is this *usually* done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have different levels of contribution.

Start by taking patches from everyone. You don't have to accept them all - if rejecting a patch, explain why it was rejected and what can be done to improve it.

For accepted patches, clean them up (and document the cleanups in a coding style guide).

The people providing the most and best patches could then get access to the repository directly and start accepting patches themselves.

At this point, accept the fact that the project is no longer just yours, though you may want to continue and lead it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll do. I've emailed the people wanting to contribute telling them that patches are welcome.

Comment: To test mid-level contributors before giving them write access, have them setup a remote tracking branch that you can pull from. It's easier/quicker than patches when it comes to contributions and it'll help establish a good source control workflow before they gain access to the remote master.

Answer (score 3):

There are as many styles of doing OSS as there are projects. The guidelines below have worked so far for *me*. YMMV.

1. Don't give write access to your repository to everyone. One of the biggest benefits of DVCS is that you don't have to, everyone gets their own repository, in principle equal to yours. Only give write access to people you *really* trust and that you know has similar views about the project.
2. Always encourage patches and pull requests. Sometimes you will have to reject some patch, however make sure you *really* justify your rejection to the contributor; people don't like being rejected without good reason and it would discourage them (and other people too, because other people *will* see the issue history in the tracker) from further contributing. Also, by pointing out what's wrong with the patch, both you and the contributor will learn from the experience.
3. Ownership is a very relative thing. If someone contributes 10 times more than you have throughout the whole history of the project, then who really owns the project? Don't worry too much about ownership, concentrate on the **project itself**. Make sure you always do what's **best for the project**. Everything else will follow naturally.

Comment: Nice points, especially that last one.

Answer (score 1):

The good point to mention here, is that other developers want to contribute to your project, because they need to change/modify/upgrade it a little bit based on their needs. If they don't have the changes committed into your project, they won't be able to easily migrate to next version.
These developers won't want you to share credit or anything. They just want their modifications/upgrades be committed.

The more developers are committing the higher chance is there that the project will be alive for a long time. The credit will be yours.